# Image segmentation in SAGA tutorials

Tags: saga, references, image-segmentation

I am searching for tutorials for the Image Segmentation modules of SAGA (version 2.0.8).
The official wiki from the software doesn't contain any info on this modules, same thing happens in the references (http://www.saga-gis.org/en/about/references.html).

Does anyone know where I can find some basic tutorials with examples on how to use those modules?

Comment: here is a tutorial http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2012/03/counting-trees-using-segmentation-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one. That is quite useful but it may require the latest version of SAGA. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwX5dBOCGYs